# Unable to send data from controller to javascript

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

This is the jsp,

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a=12;
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("button").click(function(){
      alert("inside click");
    $.post('test.htm',{inputNumber1: $("#inputNumber1").val()},function(data){
        alert(data);
        });
    alert("returned");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="inputNumber1" type="text" size="5">
<button>print</button><br>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the controller

```
package web;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/test.htm")
    public @ResponseBody Integer add(@RequestParam(value="inputNumber1", required=true) Integer inputNumber1,
            Model model) {
        System.out.println(inputNumber1);
        return inputNumber1;
    }
}
```

The inputNumber1 is being sent to the controller and it is printed, but it is not being sent back to the javascript, i.e.
`function(data){ alert(data) };`, this function is not called and so is the alert.

I have included these two jar files apart from the usual spring jars,

1. jackson-mapper-asl-1.5.2.jar
2. spring-json-1.3.1.jar

Why isn't that function being called? Is there something more that I have to include? Please help, I'm new to spring3 and jquery.

Comment: when you are sending ajax request what response you are getting in firebug?   also update to latest version jackson-mapper-asl-1.6.4.jar

Comment: i'm not using firebug. When I add the jar, jackson-core-asl-1.5.5.jar, I get the error, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper

Comment: i will suggest you to use firebug...it helps in debugging...but for now hard code the value in your controller as return 1 and see if you are getting it..also change the return type to int instead of Integer

Comment: i'm getting an exception, BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following jars have to be added to the classpath
1.jackson-core-asl-1.0.0.jar
2.jackson-mapper-asl-1.0.0.jar

and the following should be added to the dispatcher servlet

to enable annotation driven controllers, validation etc...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class TestController {
        @RequestMapping(value="/test.htm")
        public @ResponseBody int add(HttpServletRequest request) {
         int num = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("inputNumber1"));
            System.out.println(num);
            return num;
        }
    }
```